# AssociationTypeMismatch but `expected` and `got` are the same class with the same object id

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

This is a rails application. Rails 5.1, Rspec 3.6. I have a failing test in my Rspec test suite and I cannot understand the error message. As far as I can see, the association expects and gets exactly the same object, yet it is still throwing an error. I would appreciate any insight into understanding this error and working towards a fix.

The relevant (minimal) model definitions:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :membership, inverse_of: :members
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

```
class Patient < Client
  has_many :members, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The error:

```
Failure/Error: return if member.update(membership: membership, patient: person)

     ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       Patient(#47184337056660) expected, got #<Patient id: 163, ...> which is an instance of Patient(#47184337056660)
```

Comment: Add the failing test.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your spec you're expecting a class, but an object of this class is being returned.

> Patient(#47184337056660) expected, got # which is an instance of Patient(#47184337056660)

This is a key information here:
**which is an instance of**

It's hard to tell if you need to fix the specs or the code, since you didn't share the specs at all.

Answer (score 0):

For future thread readers, I found the problem:

The test had stubbed the `is_a?` method to return false for this particular `Patient` instance.

Lord knows why 3-months-ago-me did this!

Under the hood rails uses this method to confirm the correct associated object type. In this case, rails checked whether the instance `is_a?(Patient)` and it returned false. So the patient instance was acting like it was not an instance of the `Patient` class